# Access members of a list without looping through it

Tags: c#, list

I need to create a list with more than 400 items and each item has 3 properties, in c#. Like:

```
Name
    Profession
    Age
    Marital Status
```

The relevant detail is that, to access individual data, I do not want to loop over each Name with a foreach or something else, but I want to access the data directly. 
Assuming I need data from a person called Ana_Salgado, which name is stored in a string called `PersonName`, would it be possible to access these data like: `PersonName.Profession`?

Any ideas? Thank you in advance :)

Comment: No. The computer has no idea where the person you're talking about is, it has to loop. The only way to get around this is to use a different datastructure, such as a hashmap (dictionary in C#). This way you can have a key and the computer doesn't need to loop to find it.

Comment: If you use a `Dictionary` using `PersonName` as a key, you could easily do that. Otherwise, you would probably need to use a LINQ query.

Comment: If you know the index of the item you want in the list you can access it by doing `list[10].PropertyName` etc.. If you need to find a specific record you *will* need to loop through the list.

Comment: @crashmstr While you're not explicitly writing a loop yourself, LINQ queries still use loops internally.

Comment: You could use a `Dictionary<string, Person>` or a `Lookup<string, Person>`(which allows multiple person per name).

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestion, I am already applying it. I let you know the results of the changing in the performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Dictionary, in this way

```
Class Members
{
 public string Profession {get; set;}
 public string Age {get; set;}
 public string MaritalStatus {get; set;}
}

Dictionary<string, Members> dict = new Dictionary<string, Members>();
```

In this way you have a data model where the name is the key of your dictionary, and
you can use `dict["Ana_Salgado"].Age` or any of Members property.

Comment: Thank you very much! I did not know about Dictionaries yet. I'm already adding this to my XML Parser and I hope the performance increases :) Thanks again!

Comment: @ViniciusSilveira Be aware that you will have issues if you have members with the same name/key

Comment: Yeah, in a Dictionary, the first value is a KEY value as a primary key in a Database table, so you must avoid duplicated keys.

Comment: @DGibbs I got it, already thought about that to use the current method (foreach). I am just trying to figure out a way to add a `multidimensional array` to my `Dictionary` and loop over it when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Use Dictionary instead of list for example. And then you would be able write something like `myDictionary["Ana_Salgado"].Profession`

Comment: Exactyl what I'll try, you and Stefano came with the best solutions